# Commutative diagram with curved arrows, colour, and changing the style of arrows

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I am using xy matrix and I would to curve an arrow over other arrows in a diagram, at the same time as setting some of these curved arrows to equal and changing their colour. This is what I have so far:

```
\usepackage[all]{xy}

    \xymatrix{
    &&H(Z) \ar@/^2.0pc/[rr]^{F(f^{op} \circ g^{op})} \ar[r]^{H^{*}(g^{op})} & H(Y) \ar@{=}[dl] \ar[r]^{H^{*}(f^{op})} & H(X) \ar@{=}[dl] \ar@/^2.0pc/[ddll]\\
    & H(Z) \ar@{=}[ur] & H(Y) \ar[u]_{G(g^{op})} & H(X) \ar@{=}[dl] \ar[u]_{G(f^{op})}\\
    H(Z) \ar[r]^{H^{*}(g^{op})} \ar@{=}[ur]  &H(Y) \ar@{=}[ur] \ar[r]^{H^{*}(f^{op})}  \ar[u]_{G(g^{op})} &H(X)   \ar[u]_{G(f^{op})} \ar@/^2.0pc/[uu]^{G(f^{op} \circ g^{op})}  \\
    }
```

I would like the larger curved arrows to be red, with the curved arrow in the bottom right hand corner of the diagram to be an = arrow as in `ar@{=}[ddll]`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a possible solution using the `color` option for the `xy` package and the `xcolor` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[all,color]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
& & H(Z) \ar@/^2.0pc/@[red][rr]^{F(f^{op} \circ g^{op})} \ar[r]^{H^{*}(g^{op})} 
  & H(Y) \ar@{=}[dl] \ar[r]^{H^{*}(f^{op})} 
  & H(X) \ar@{=}[dl] \ar@/^2.0pc/@{=>}@[red][ddll] \\
& H(Z) \ar@{=}[ur] 
  & H(Y) \ar[u]_{G(g^{op})} 
  & H(X) \ar@{=}[dl] \ar[u]_{G(f^{op})} \\
H(Z) \ar[r]_{H^{*}(g^{op})} \ar@{=}[ur] 
  & H(Y) \ar@{=}[ur] \ar[r]_{H^{*}(f^{op})}  \ar[u]_{G(g^{op})}
  & H(X)  \ar[u]_{G(f^{op})} 
  \ar@/^2.0pc/@[red][uu]^{G(f^{op} \circ g^{op})}
}

\end{document}
```

The above code will produce the following result (I only focused my answer on the problems mentioned in the question; the layout of the diagram has to be improved to avoid overlapping elements):

[image]

Changing the column spacing, overlapping element are prevented:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[all,color]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix@C=2cm{
& & H(Z) \ar@/^2.0pc/@[red][rr]^{F(f^{op} \circ g^{op})} \ar[r]^{H^{*}(g^{op})} 
  & H(Y) \ar@{=}[dl] \ar[r]^{H^{*}(f^{op})} 
  & H(X) \ar@{=}[dl] \ar@/^2.0pc/@{=>}@[red][ddll] \\
& H(Z) \ar@{=}[ur] 
  & H(Y) \ar[u]_{G(g^{op})} 
  & H(X) \ar@{=}[dl] \ar[u]_{G(f^{op})} \\
H(Z) \ar[r]_{H^{*}(g^{op})} \ar@{=}[ur] 
  & H(Y) \ar@{=}[ur] \ar[r]_{H^{*}(f^{op})}  \ar[u]_{G(g^{op})}
  & H(X)  \ar[u]_{G(f^{op})} 
  \ar@/^2.0pc/@[red][uu]^{G(f^{op} \circ g^{op})}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, a package that could be of interest for you is [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd).

Comment: Any sufficiently advanced `xymatrix` code is indistinguishable from complicated regex.

Comment: @Seamus: `xymatrix` code is a lot more readable if you start a new line for every node, and when an arrow is particularly messy put it on a new line as well.

Comment: @PhilHirschhorn you're right. I used your suggestion to improve the example code readability. Thanks.