# dotted or colored arc in \xymatrix

Tags: color, arrows, xy-pic, arc

Does not arrows style or color option apply an arc in `\xymatrix`? Please let me know the way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[arrow, matrix]{xy}
\begin{document}
  \[
    \xymatrix{
      A \ar@{.>} `d[r] `r[dr] [dr]& \\ & B
    }
  \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello Yuki, welcome to the site. If you indent your lines with 4 spaces they are marked as code. So you don't need to escape the markup chars.

Comment: Oh, I had overlooked. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Does [Coloring arrows in `\xymatrixhelp`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7058/35864) or [Commutative diagram with curved arrows, colour, and changing the style of arrows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63257/35864) you?

Comment: I could color or dot the straight parts of the arrow like your links, but the arc parts are not changed.

Comment: It might be a lot more flexible if you use the `tikz-cd` package instead. It is almost the same syntax, the arrow macros are named differently. Plus the bonus of all the `tikz` tricks

Comment: Thanks daleif, I had achieved my purpose to use tikz-cd. How merciless the changes of mainstreams!

Comment: @Yuki Have found some solution to your problem in the meantime? I would be very interested. If not, you could accept my answer in order to close this post as solved or you rewrite your question asking explicitly for `xy` and I will put a bounty on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not manage to obtain your desired result with `xy`. But here you have a solution with `tikz-cd`:

```
% arara: pdflatex 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[draw=none]{dr}[name=aux, anchor = center]{} \arrow[rounded corners=7pt, dotted, red, to path={ (\tikztostart.south)
                      |- (aux.center) \tikztonodes
                      -| (\tikztotarget.north)
                      }]{dr}& \\
    & B
    \end{tikzcd}
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]